# Mathematical expression in a section title with distinct font

Tags: fonts

I need to write a mathematical expression in a section title, for example this:
`\section{$Al_{2}O_{3}$}`, 
but in this case it will appear in a math style (in italic font.) I don't know how could I force the latex to write it normal as a normal text, (as a bold and not italic letter).

Comment: Answer: it depends on information you have chosen not to share. Please provide a minimal document which we can compile to reproduce what you see now. Discussion: this will greatly confuse your readers. I'm no mathematician but, as I understand it italic and upright have different semantic meanings. So do bold and normal weight. How, then, should your readers understand the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\textsubscript{2}` etc. for the indices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}` % for LaTeX older than early 2015
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\section{$Al_{2}O_{3}$}

\section{Al\textsubscript{2}O\textsubscript{3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Hajnus: Normally, you don't need `fixltx2e` any longer. The fixes from that package have been incorporated into the LaTeX core this year

Comment: I don't know why, but when I tried it without this usepackage it didn't work.

Comment: @Hajnus: Apparently you have an older LaTeX distribution. I will add the package to the solution

Answer (score 7):

This is not mathematics, but chemistry!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\section{\ch{Al2O3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but in the general case it refer to a mathematics expression. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Hajnus If it's math, it should be typeset as math. Is the problem about boldface? Some styles make math bold in section titles (I wouldn't). In this case just do `\section{\protect\boldmath $x+y=z$}`